# Auto-close of brackets during Emmet expressions doesn't work (WebStorm)

Tags: webstorm

In WebStorm, when I write an Emmet expression in html, the brackets and carets do not get their pair automatically. I need to place them by myself.

Is there any way to configure Emmet in WebStorm?

[image: example of i am writhing about]

Comment: I do not think it has anything to do with Emmet. It must be that this functionality works only in predefined contexts (e.g. in PHP or JavaScript files where such pairing is common/obvious/expected). In your case this seems to be just plain-text context (you did not have code completion for your actual `article>h3` string) where you can type any sequence .. so that "smart keys" functionality is disabled here.

Comment: Right now I may only suggest to check their Issue Tracker (the following 2 projects) and see if you can find any existing tickets; if none found -- submit one yourself. 1) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB 2) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: Just hit this problem too. Brackets and quotes should be auto-paired in html files if you have that smart key setting checked.  The auto pair features are not working, plain and simple.  It reduces the convenience of emmet in html files when you are trying to consume custom components with custom attributes.  It doesn't matter if I'm working in plain-text context or not.  A starting quote or bracket always needs a closing one, especially if I have auto pair checked.